# how to format 2 check buttons in same row and column python

Tags: python

I have created two check buttons and I want them both in row 5 and column 1. But I want the 'YES' check button to be formatted on the left side and the 'NO' check button to be on the right.

I have used sticky but it will not work. I also tried changing the width of the check buttons but this did not work either.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you!

```
self.yes_checkbtn = Checkbutton(self.entry_frame, width = 20, variable = checkbutton1, 
                                anchor = W, text = "YES")
self.no_checkbtn = Checkbutton(self.entry_frame, width = 20, variable = checkbutton2, 
                               anchor = E, text = "NO")

self.yes_checkbtn.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = W)
self.no_checkbtn.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = E)
```

Outcome:

[image]

I dont have enough points yet to show the image without a link - sorry

Comment: Change ```column``` in ```self.no_checkbtn.grid()``` to 2. Because in my machine, it is basically overlapping the buttons

Comment: yes I realise this but would there be a way to have them in the same column and no overlap, as when I make 2 columns they are very wide

Comment: Ok, then try: ```self.yes_checkbtn.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = W,columnspan=1,ipadx=40)
        self.no_checkbtn.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = E)```

Answer (score 0):

Put both check buttons under another new frame, then you can grid this new frame to column 1 of row 5, also change option width of Checkbutton to a small number, like 5.

Example code

[image]

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

entry_frame = Frame(root)
entry_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(2):
        label = Label(entry_frame, text=f'Row {i} Column {j}')
        label.grid(row=i, column=j)

frame = Frame(entry_frame)
frame.grid(row=4, column=1)

checkbutton1 = BooleanVar()
checkbutton2 = BooleanVar()

yes_checkbtn = Checkbutton(frame, width = 5, variable = checkbutton1,
    anchor = W, text = "YES", bg='green')
no_checkbtn  = Checkbutton(frame, width = 5, variable = checkbutton2,
    anchor = E, text = "NO", bg='blue')
yes_checkbtn.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)
no_checkbtn.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = W)

root.mainloop()
```